# Как сделать выборку SQL без вложенных запросов?

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть две таблицы

1. `messages`: `id` (auto_inc), `topic_id`, `user_id`, `message`
2. `user_type`: `user_id`, `type_id`

Значения `type_id` захардкожены:
1 - модератор
2 - юзер

Задача: Выбрать по одной последней записи на каждый топик, где `user_id` модератор

P.S. - Модераторов и юзеров может быть множество.

Comment: что такое `user` в первой таблице? это `user_id` или что?

Comment: без вложенных запросов => самоджойн

Comment: Какой запрос подскажите пожалуйста?